# Using P/Invoke on structs and pointers

Tags: c#, api, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to use P/Invoke to call some functions in a third party native DLL.
But I keep receiving FatalExecutionEngine error.
Probably I'm making some mistake against the marshalling of data or ?

This is the native function I'm trying to use:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void dw_mm_directional_spectrum_initialise(
    struct dw_mm_directional_spectrum_T* directional_spectrum
    , const enum dw_buoy_type_T buoy_type
    , const unsigned char status[ /* NULL || sample_count */ ]
    , const double v[ /* sample_count */ ]
    , const double n[ /* sample_count */ ]
    , const double w[ /* sample_count */ ]
    , const unsigned int sample_count);
```

This is the native struct which is returned through a pointer:

```
struct dw_mm_directional_spectrum_T{
    signed char error_code;
    double* c_vv;
    double* c_nn;
    double* c_ww;
    double* c_nw;
    double* q_vn;
    double* q_vw;
    unsigned short output_size;
    double fraction_of_segments_used;
    unsigned char* list_of_used_segments;
    unsigned short list_of_used_segments_size;
};
```

This is the struct definition in the C# program:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct datawell{
    Byte error_code;
    double[] c_vv;
    double[] c_nn;
    double[] c_ww;
    double[] c_nw;
    double[] q_vn;
    double[] q_vw;
    ushort output_size;
    double fraction_of_segments_used;
    IntPtr list_of_used_segments;
    ushort list_of_used_segments_size;
};
```

My DLLimport signature:

```
[DllImport("libwaves.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void dw_mm_directional_spectrum_initialise(
    out datawell dw,
    Byte buoy_type,
    Byte[] status,
    double[] v,
    double[] n,
    double[] w,
    ushort sample_count);
```

And this is how I use the function in my C# program:

```
double[] vertical = new double[512]; 
double[] north = new double[512];
double[] west = new double[512];
Byte[] status = new Byte[512];
datawell dw_test = new datawell();
ushort cnt = 512;

//dummy data generation
for(int i=0;i<512;i++){
    status[i]=1;
    vertical[i]=i*1.0;
    north[i]=i*1.0;
    west[i]=i*1.0;
}

dw_mm_directional_spectrum_initialise(out dw_test,0,status, vertical, north,west,cnt);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Zjerre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot marshal the pointers contained in the struct as C# arrays. You are going to need to declare them as `IntPtr`, and then marshal them yourself. You'll need `Marshal.Copy()` for that process.

I'm not sure about the memory ownership rules. Presumably the native code allocates the arrays that come back in the struct? If so then I guess you'll have to call the native library again when you are done with the struct so that it can deallocate the arrays.

Comment: David thanks for your answer. You're completly right. There is a function to destroy the allocated memory which takes the returned struct as an input.

After declaring the arrays as IntPtrs and marshal.copying them it working without any issues.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`list_of_used_segments` is defined as `unsigned char*` in C and `double[]` in C#.

Comment: SLaks,

Thanks for the answer. I changed the type to IntPtr but still the same error.